# Assigning when returning a value

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I'm not understanding a function used by my co-worker. He cannot
He is using strange return blocks.

```
block_t *get_block(void *p)
{
    char *tmp;
    tmp = p;
    return (p = tmp -= 16);
}
```

He says it is supposed to return form and the address.

Need some help to understand the return ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you have some code to illustrate how this function is used?

Comment: Your co-worker should be fired.

Comment: @n.m. Or promoted, so he won't write any code :)

Comment: I am just curious... Is this the actual code you have or it is trimmed down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All C operators compute values (except a cast operator with `void` as the target type or a function call to a function returning `void`).  In particular, assignment and op/assignment operations evaluate to the value assigned.  Therefore, this statement:

> ```
>     return (p = tmp -= 16);
> ```

is equivalent to

```
    tmp -= 16;
    p = tmp;
    return p;
```

**And the latter is exactly how *I* would write it** if that's what I wanted to do.  Compacting it all into one expression makes the code harder for a human to read and understand, and conveys no offsetting advantage whatsoever.

HOWEVER, your particular case is even worse.  In your case, `p` and `tmp` are local variables of the function, so assignments to them have no effect on the caller.  There is therefore no point in assigning a new value to `p` if it will not afterward be read back (from `p`).  This may or may not reflect a programming error.  If the function's actual behavior is correct as-is, then I would write the overall function much differently:

```
block_t *get_block(void *p) {
    return (block_t *) (((char *) p) - 16);
}
```

Comment: Moreover, it contains useless steps: The `p` and `tmp` are local variables that will be destroyed after the return statement anyhow. You don't have to save the value of `p` before altering. Furthermore, your code is equivalent to just `block_t *get_block(void *p) {return ((char *)p) - 16;}` .

Comment: Agreed, @MichaelBeer.  I was updating this answer to say just the same when you wrote your comment.

Comment: Wasn't meant to critize upon the valid answer. I think the assignment stuff in the original code is mainly there to avoid compiler warnings due to type casts?

Comment: No worries, @MichaelBeer, I didn't take it as a criticism.  As I said, I had the exact same thought at about the same time.

Comment: Re “All C operators compute values”: Except cast to void and a function with return type void. 

Comment: Acknowledged and updated, @EricPostpischil.  One of these days I'll learn to be more careful about slinging around "all".

Comment: The replacement code needs a final cast to `void *` or `block_t *`. Otherwise, it attempts to return a `char *` for a `block_t *`, which are probably incompatible types. Hmm, at that point, it is getting kind of messy visually. So I can sort of see the visual appeal and entertainment value of `return p = tmp -= 16;`, not that I would recommend it.

Comment: I had to check, @EricPostpischil, but contrary to what I thought I knew, `char *` and `block_t *` indeed do seem to be incompatible types.  I've added the cast.  I do see what you mean about the somewhat complicated expression, but I don't think it's bad enough for me, personally, to add a temporary variable.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special with `return`. It is just an expression as in any other place.

You could rewrite it as follows:

```
block_t *get_block(void *p)
{
    char *tmp = p;
    p = tmp - 16;
    return p;
}
```

or

```
block_t *get_block(void *p)
{
    char *tmp = p;
    tmp -= 16;
    p = tmp;
    return p;
}
```

or

```
block_t *get_block(void *p)
{
    char *tmp = p;
    tmp -= 16;
    return (block_t *)tmp;
}
```

The assignment within the `return` statement does not have any effect after you return from that function.

What it does is basically calculating the address 16 bytes before the address that you provide.
This might be some memory management where you store some data in a header before the memory location the user is given.

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy, but very incorrect , not portable and error prone.

He takes the address 16 chars earlier and returns A it. He need to do pointer arithmetic on char pointer so he needs to make it char. The second assignment is not needed